# Handling Empty Result Set When Scanning Backward in DynamoDB Pagination

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

I'm working on a DynamoDB project and need to implement pagination using the GetNextSetAsync() method from the AWS SDK for .NET. I'm facing a specific challenge when performing backward (reverse) queries in DynamoDB.

In DynamoDB, the last evaluated key is expected to represent the starting point for the next page of results. However, when this last evaluated key points to the very end of the table and the first element of the last page, I'm getting an empty result set. Under normal circumstances, I expect the last evaluated key record to be part of the result set when querying backward.

My approach to handling backward pagination involves querying for an additional record and then creating a pagination token from the last record. Afterward, I remove the last record from the result set. I'm using [FromQueryAsync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/DynamoDBv2/MIDynamoDBContextFromQueryAsyncQueryOperationConfigDynamoDBOperationConfig.html) method from the DynamoDBContext class for querying.

Here is an example for using the AWS SDK https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/e68209ef191d825e7b19dd5b0ea84a980df54922/dotnetv3/dynamodb/scenarios/DynamoDB_Basics/DynamoDB_Actions/DynamoDbMethods.cs#L297-L346

Here is a simplified version of my code that handles both forward and backward pagination:

```
// ... Code for initializing the DynamoDB context and search

var data = new List<TEntity>();
bool hasItemsBefore = false;
bool hasItemsAfter = false;

while (!search.IsDone && data.Count < page.PageSize)
{
    data.AddRange(await search.GetNextSetAsync());
}

TEntity nextItem = default(TEntity);
TEntity prevItem = default(TEntity);

if (// condition to check for backward pagination)
{
    // Backward pagination
    hasItemsBefore = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageTokenData.DynamoPageKey());
    hasItemsAfter = data.Count > page.PageSize || !search.IsDone;
    nextItem = data.Last();
    data = data.Take(page.PageSize).ToList();
}
else
{
    // Forward pagination
    hasItemsAfter = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageTokenData.DynamoPageKey());
    hasItemsBefore = data.Count > page.PageSize || !search.IsDone;
    data = data.Take(page.PageSize).ToList();
    nextItem = data.First();
    data.Reverse();
}
prevItem = data.First();
PaginationTokenData? nextPageToken = null;
PaginationTokenData? prevPageToken = null;

if (hasItemsAfter)
{
    nextPageToken = new PaginationTokenData(
        page.Descending,
        _context.GetDynamoKeyEntry(nextItem, indexName)!
    );
}

if (hasItemsBefore)
{
    prevPageToken = new PaginationTokenData(
        !page.Descending,
        _context.GetDynamoKeyEntry(prevItem, indexName)!
    );
}

var result = new PaginationResult<TEntity>
{
    Data = data,
    PageSize = data.Count,
    PrevPageToken = prevPageToken?.ToToken(),
    NextPageToken = nextPageToken?.ToToken()
};
```

I'd appreciate any advice or insights on how to handle the situation where the last evaluated key is the last element in the table, and ensure that it's included in the result set during backward querying.

Comment: DynamoDB does not natively support backwards `Scanning`. If you start on the last item in the table, its expected that the LastEvaluatedKey is null/empty. Are you using Scan or Query?

Comment: @LeeroyHannigan It's querying. Sorry if my question misled to belive it's a scan. I'll update it. GetNextSetAsync() from AWS SDK is used for a query operation from what I know.

Comment: I just did some more reading and turns out `GetNextSetAsync` can be used for both scan and query. My use case is a query operation using `FromQueryAsync` method of the DynamoDB context class

Comment: Ive posted an answer which I believe should answer your concerns, please feel free to let me know if something is missing.

Comment: In this case, I'm creating my own LEK so how can I overcome my initial problem of querying when LEK is the last record of the query operation? Is there another approach that I should consider or should I stick with one with some changes? One approach I can think of is querying specifically for the LEK record when the result set in empty using key attributes.

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB `Query` only returns items for a given partition key, and you can choose to set `ScanIndexForward=False` (DESC), or `ScanIndexForward=True` (ASC) to determine which direction to read the items.

If `LastEvaluatedKey` is present in the response, you will need to paginate the result set, if it is not, then you know you have read all the items in that item collection.

Given the following item collection, we can determine when no `LastEvaluatedKey` would be returned:

| PK | SK |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 1 | D |
| 1 | E |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |

A query in either direction when the item-colleciton size is less than 1MB would not return an LEK. However, if we used Limit we can force it to return an LEK.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE PK = 1 LIMIT 2 ASC
-----
LEK = 1 | B
```

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE PK = 1 LIMIT 2 DESC
-----
LEK = 1 | D
```

So above DynamoDB determines that there are more items left to read, so it returns a LEK. But if we reach the end of the range, then we will not get an LEK:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE PK = 1 AND EXCLUSIVE_START_KEY=1|E LIMIT 2 ASC
-----
LEK = NULL
```

**Its important to note that the Query will never make it to the value `PK=2` as that is a different item collection, and Query will only ever act on a single item collection.**

Comment: In my case, I'm using the limit attribute as well with a value greater then the required page size. The response does not contain a LEK but just the result set as indicated in the docs here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/MDynamoDBv2DataModelAsyncSearch%601GetNextSetAsyncCancellationTokenNET45.html

Comment: But if you read the entire collection in a single page, there would be no LEK, thats expected as there is nothing left to read.

Comment: Understood. I still wonder what's the use of the Limit attribute which is present in my query config object for the async search https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/DynamoDBv2/TQueryOperationConfig.html

Comment: I just read that Limit is applied to the result set after a table is queried. In my case, I'm creating my own LEK so how can I overcome my initial problem of querying when LEK is the last record of the query operation? Is there another approach that I should consider or should I stick with one with some changes? One approach I can think of is querying specifically for the LEK record when the result set in empty using key attributes.

Comment: But if you query for the last record, why would you want an LEK? If no more items are in ASC order for example, you've nothing left to read. If its to page backwards, use the item that was returned as your LEK.

Comment: It so happens that sometimes the LEK is the last record in the result set (or page) as well as the last record for those query conditions. I create a LEK out of it and query for the next set but now the LEK is not returned in the result set since it's the last record and the next set is empty which means that the result sets would never contain the LEK record. Note that in the case of backward querying, LEK record is included in the next result set unlike forward paginated querying.